# Customize NgbModal size

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I'm using `Angular 6` and `NgbModal` like

```
openViewDescriptionModal(id) {
  const viewModal = this.modalService.open(ProductComponent, {size: 'lg'});
}
```

But this opens modal with width 50% only with 25% space empty on both sides.

I want to redesign modal width to up to 90% of the window width.

But there are only `sm` and `lg` sizes allowed with `NgbModal`.

How can I increase the width of the modal or probably use a custom class to increase modal width?

I tried setting values like `xl` to `size` but it does not work.
I also tried customizing the CSS of the modal class but this did not work either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the 'windowClass' property referencing some class, so your code would be like:

```
openViewDescriptionModal(id) {
  const viewModal = this.modalService.open(ProductComponent, {size: 'lg', windowClass: 'modal-xl'});
}
```

and then, on some .css you're using, add your own class with the custom size to override like:

```
.modal-xl .modal-lg {
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me only when i set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,`

Comment: This solution worked for me! struggled for lot of time...

Comment: This answer is not correct. The `windowClass` is set to content of the modal, not the modal itself. See my solution which actually works on the modal itself. The given solution could be working as the user has changed the value of `.modal-lg` itself, which is not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can also manipulate this size just by changing the value of the "size" variable!
`this.modalContent, {backdrop: 'static',size: 'sm', keyboard: false, centered: true}`

Answer (score 2):

None of this answers are accurate. There's a far easier solution. Use the `size` option to pass some custom name, let's say `mysize`:

```
this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'mysize' });
```

Now, set the CSS class `modal-mysize` to whatever size you want. This class is applied to the actual modal window, so you can use it to customize other stuff as well. The following will set the width to 200px:

```
.modal-mysize {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Hope this helps!